# Change the mouse pointer using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mouse-cursor, custom-cursor

I wanted to use a script to change the mouse pointer on my website using JavaScript.
It's better done by CSS but my requirement is of a script that can be distributed to many people to embed in the head section of their websites.
Through CSS, this can be manipulated by

```
html
{
    cursor: *cursorurl*
}
```

How to do the same in JavaScript?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

JavaScript is pretty good at manipulating CSS:

```
 document.body.style.cursor = *cursor-url*;
 //OR
 var elementToChange = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
 elementToChange.style.cursor = "url('cursor url with protocol'), auto";
```

or with jQuery:

```
$("html").css("cursor: url('cursor url with protocol'), auto");
```

Firefox **will not work** unless you specify a default cursor after the imaged one!

[other cursor keywords](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_class_cursor.asp)

Also remember that IE6 only supports [.cur and .ani cursors](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csscursors.shtml).

**If cursor doesn't change:** In case you are moving the element under the cursor relative to the cursor position (e.g. element dragging) you have to force a redraw on the element:

```
// in plain js
document.getElementById('parentOfElementToBeRedrawn').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('parentOfElementToBeRedrawn').style.display = 'block';
// in jquery
$('#parentOfElementToBeRedrawn').hide().show(0);
```

---

working sample:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.cursor = "url('http://wiki-devel.sugarlabs.org/images/e/e2/Arrow.cur'), auto";
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <body>
    <div>
    hello with a fancy cursor!
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried this                                                                        <script type="text/javascript">
var elementsToChange = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
elementsToChange.style.cursor = (http://wiki-devel.sugarlabs.org/images/e/e2/Arrow.cur);                                                                                                                                This was giving me an error. Pardon me, I am actually total new to JS.

Comment: @user sorry, answer edited. You need to add url('') and put the actual url between the quotation marks. :D

Comment: Hey! Thanks for help. I changed that but it's still not working for me. Here-> http://textb.in/3a

Answer (score 20):

Look at this page: http://www.webcodingtech.com/javascript/change-cursor.php.  Looks like you can access cursor off of style.  This page shows it being done with the entire page, but I'm sure a child element would work just as well.

```
document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
```

Comment: This does work, on the premise that the cursor is actually moved, otherwise it remains with existing cursor

Answer (score 15):

```
document.body.style.cursor = 'cursorurl';
```

Answer (score 0):

Body may have margin, so better solution will be:

```js
document.documentElement.style.cursor = 'pointer';
```