# Javascript-firefox: how to set custom cursor from local png file?

Tags: javascript, firefox, cursor

how do you set a custom cursor for the current page from a local image file? basically I need to change to a different cursor programmatically using javascript, but the cursor is stored locally on my hard drive.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564251/change-the-mouse-pointer-using-javascript

Comment: yes but how to indicate local file url? im guessing this is not possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't (*but see below*), because the `file://` cannot be accessed or referred from other protocols.

> The basic way to include a cursor through JavaScript is:
>
> ```
> element.style.cursor = "url(...location-of-pic...), auto";
> //                                                ^^^^^^ (required as fallback)
> ```

1. You can [convert your image to a base64-dataURI](http://www.greywyvern.com/code/php/binary2base64), and use it instead of `file://..../cursor.png`:

   ```
   document.documentElement.style.cursor = 'url("data:image/x-icon;base64,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%3D%3D"), auto';
   ```

   You can upload and convert any file to base-64 format at [this page](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp). Trim the whitespace, and prefix `data:image/png;base64,`.
2. Instead of using data-URIs, an image can also be uploaded to a file host, and embedded as follows:

   ```
   document.documentElement.style.cursor = 'url("http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico"), auto';
   ```

See also:

- MDN: [CSS `cursor` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/cursor)
- MDN: [Using URL values for the `cursor` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property)

Comment: would setting `cursor = "default";` change to default cursor?

Comment: @KimJongWoo Use `.style.cursor = '';` (empty string) to undo your action.

Comment: btw, this works but the default hand cursor shows up when you mouse over a link. how to override the default? is it possible to set style cursor to all elements on the dom document?

Comment: @KimJongWoo That's because the user agent defines a `cursor` CSS property for anchors. If you want to override all `cursor` properties, use [`document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('*{cursor:url(...),default !important;}',0)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) (IE: [`addRule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358796(v=vs.85).aspx). This code assumes that you've already got a `styleSheet` object (`<style>`) in the document, from the same origin. Otherwise, create a `<style>` element, and append it before using the specific metod.

Comment: `document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('*{cursor: url("data:image/x-icon;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA...."),default !important;}',0);` ? firefox throws security error.

Comment: @KimJongWoo The first style sheet in your document is from an external URL. If you want an easy way to insert the CSS, [create a `<style>` elemen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript), and attach an `id` to it (so that you can remove it at a later point, to undo the styles).

Comment: Thanks so much, this really helps, and I do consider this question as not duplicating with the suggested one.