# Custom cursor image by url

Tags: javascript, css, url, cursor

I'm trying to make a small script that changes CSS of the body and the  cursor on the page to a cursor at a specified URL.

```
var cursorurl=prompt('Enter url of a image you want to use as a cursor on this page');
document.body.style.cursor="url("+cursorurl+"), auto;";
```

The javascript appears to be valid, but the cursor doesn't change. I'm assuming it has something to do with `document.body.style.cursor="url("+cursorurl+"), auto;"` and the parentheses, but if it is then I'm not sure how to do it properly.

Comment: Anything coming up in your console? Think you may have to use: document.body.style.cursor = "url(" + cursorurl + "), auto"; (notice "document" before "body")

Comment: Also, ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408780/javascript-firefox-how-to-set-custom-cursor-from-local-png-file

Comment: @PaulG No errors in the console. Tried using document.body instead of just body, still no result.