# not able to change custom cursors in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a online game 'tic tac toe' using buttons in html, to make it attractive I want to use custom cursors like 'X' and 'O' and it should change alternately with each click, when tried in Microsoft frontpage 2003 I succeeded but when opened in google chrome and IE browser cursor is not changing.

I tried various methods but not able to complete that...

```
function cha1(){
    if(mat[0]==0){
        if(i%2==0){
            bt1.innerHTML="O";
            mat[0]=2;
        }
        else{
            bt1.innerHTML="X";
            mat[0]=1;
        }
        i=i+1;
        bt1.style.cursor='url("../cursor/no.gif")','auto';
        bt1.style.cursor='url("../cursor/no.cur")','auto';
    }
    check();
}
```

there are no errors or anything but the regular pointer cursor is not changing to my custom cursor. I already hosted that page if you want to visit click here "http://airgame.ml/XandO/". Please help me with this issue, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi please refer to the post below https://stackoverflow.com/a/9409934/7855321

Comment: You're explicitly setting `cursor` to `auto`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: I tried your methods but went unsuccessful. From your response, I think this is the change you wanted. 
             bt9.style.cursor='url("../cursor/no.gif"),auto';
             bt9.style.cursor='url("../cursor/no.cur"),auto';

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved that,

```
bt9.style.cursor='url("http:airgame.ml /cursor/no.gif"),auto';
```

is the appropriate syntax for it. 
Thanks guys for helping me.

Comment: There's a space in `.ml /`. It shouldn't be there, right?