# Proper way to show a "wait" cursor in a C# / ASP web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, mouse-cursor

I'm trying to display a wait cursor in a web app I'm building, when I came upon this question/answer:

[How can I make the cursor turn to the wait cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29434110/2174085)

The answer mentions `This.UseWaitCursor`, but it's not appearing in Intellisense.

My question; is this the proper usage in a web application?  If so, do I need a certain Namespace to use it?  If not, what is the proper way to display a wait cursor so that it will display a circle/hourglass/whatever until I request that it change back to the standard cursor?

Comment: `UseWaitCursor` is only available in WinForms. In a web application you have to change the cursor client side, with javascript for istance. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564251/change-the-mouse-pointer-using-javascript